# Error after passing variable from jquery to code in c#

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I try to pass variable from jquery to code c# but something is wrong. I have in js this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mySerial = '12345';
    var fooUrl = '@Url.Action("Foo", "Home")';
    window.location.href = fooUrl + '?mySerial' + encodeURIComponent(mySerial);
</script>
```

in controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(string mySerial)
{
    return View();
}
```

After execution I keep this url: `http://localhost:2214/@Url.Action("Foo",%20"Home")?mySerial12345` and I don't understand where's the problem, can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the equal sign:

```
window.location.href = fooUrl + '?mySerial=' + encodeURIComponent(mySerial);
```

Notice `mySerial=` instead of `mySerial`.

By the way it seems that you are using the WebForms view engine and not Razor, at least that's the conclusion I draw if you see the `@Url.Action` literal in your generated output. If this is the case please use the proper syntax according to the view engine you are using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mySerial = '12345';
    var fooUrl = '<%= Url.Action("Foo", "Home") %>';
    window.location.href = fooUrl + '?mySerial=' + encodeURIComponent(mySerial);
</script>
```

Final remark: if this is in a separate javascript file you cannot use server side helpers such as `Url.Action`. It doesn't seem to be in a separate file because I can see the `<script>` inline tag but that's what you have shown here, maybe in your actual code this is in a separate file.